# set up rejection regions given 2 populations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, multiple-comparisons, small-sample, rejection-sampling

I need to set up rejection regions given these problems.  I am very new to statistics.  However, I don't know what formula to use to get those regions.

One formula that I think I might use is given by my textbook, but it requires you to know the value of the s1 and s2.  See attached screenshot.

[![Confidence Interval for
μ1 - μ2, Independent
Samples][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcdpo.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcdpo.jpg)

a)
H0: μ1 = μ2 versus H0: μ1 != μ2, with n1=11, n2=14, and α=.05

b)
H0: μ1 <= μ2 versus H0: μ1 > μ2, with n1= n2=7, and α=.01

c)
H0: μ1 >= μ2 versus H0: μ1 < μ2, with n1=8, n2=9, and α=.025

Answer (score 0):

The given data is incomplete. 
One must know the values of s1 and s2
OR
It is to be given that the two populations have equal variances.

Once one of these two things are provided you can use t-test rejection regions preferably or z-test rejection regions to find out the required rejection regions.